# Class in variable works wrong

Tags: javascript

I have a very complicated problem: I'm making app that works like linux terminal. So I type command and app do something.
This is one of my classes:

```
function _console() {
    this.name = "console";
    this.command_list = {
        "help": function () {
            this.app = function () {
                write("Sorry, no commands so far ;P");
                return this;
            };
            this.help = "type to get help";
            return this;
        }
    };

    this.start = function () {
        write("Hi :)");
    };

    return this;
};
```

I keep this class in array:

```
var mainData = {
    openedApps: new Array(new _console()),
};
```

The problem is: first use of "help" function works fine. But when I type it again appears an error:

> TypeError: Property 'help' of object # is not a function

This is how I execute my function:

```
mainData.openedApps[0].command_list["help"]().app();
```

I have another class, very similar to this I paste here, except I don't keep it in variable.
I execute it like:

```
_global_commands().command_list["command"]().app();
```

This works fine, so I think this is problem with keeping my class inside var. But I really don't know what I've made wrong.

Comment: This line is switching the help function with a string `this.help = "type to get help";`

Comment: Which line?  I don't understand you :/

Comment: I've wrote you the exact line. `this.help = "type to get help";` You're replacing the pointer to the function with a string.

Comment: why? you mean: "help": sth is equal to this.help?

Comment: exactly. They are the same

Answer (score 1):

You have a few peculiarities there. Firstly, why redeclare `help`'s methods every time it's called, rather than just once?

There are several ways to do this. One, below, solves your problem.

```
"help": function() {
    this.app = this.app || function(){
        write("Sorry, no commands so far ;P");
        return this;
    };
    this.help = this.help || "type to get help";
    return this;
}
```

Moreover, you should consider declaring methods on a prototype rather than inside constructors. For your use-case, this might not present an observable problem, but the result is that your methods are methods of the instance, not inheritable methods of the class. (Inheritance is also faster than looking up on the instance, according to some benchmark tests done by jQuery founder John Resig).